# Accessing the color or other properties of the control element in the collectionview in MAUI

Tags: maui

Hifriends.I have a list with multiple buttons. And whichever of these buttons I press, I want it to remain active and the others to return to normal. I tried VisualState for this but it didn't work the way I wanted. Finally I tried to write something on the behind-code. However, although it works perfectly on WinUI, on Android the color I set occurs randomly on multiple buttons even though they cannot be clicked. Does anyone have any ideas or solutions to this?

I am binding it in MAUI in CollectionView as:

XAML:

```html
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollectionView" ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}" ItemsLayout="HorizontalList" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="characters:Character">
            <HorizontalStackLayout Margin="10">
            
                <Button Clicked="Button_Clicked" BackgroundColor="DarkGray" />
            
            </HorizontalStackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>         
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Behind-Codes in C#:

```
Button tempBeforeButtonForColor = new Button();

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tempBeforeButtonForColor.BackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGray;
    tempBeforeButtonForColor = sender as Button;
    (sender as Button).BackgroundColor = Color.FromArgb("daa520");

}
```

Comment: 1. Do you mean you only want the pressed Button's to the Color `Color.FromArgb("daa520");` and the rest ones remain `Colors.DarkGray;`? 2. Your behind code is not enough, could you please create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and add it to your post?

Comment: Exactly! That's what I meant. I thought my problem was self-explanatory. Sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need wrap the Button with [Boder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/border?view=net-maui-8.0) to get it worked. Also, you may need to set the `Normal` state to  `<Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkGray" />`.

Here's the XAML code for your reference:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChanged="myCollectionView_SelectionChanged">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="characters:Character">
                        <Border Padding="40"
            StrokeShape="Rectangle 40 40 40 40"
            
            HorizontalOptions="Center">
                          <Label Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>

                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="DarkGray" />
                                         
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <VisualState.Setters>
                                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#daa520" />
                                        </VisualState.Setters>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 </CollectionView>
```

**Android:**

[image]

**Windows:**

[image]

Comment: You are great. Actually, I tried border. But by drawing my attention with your example, you helped me find something that was closest to my goal. Thanks.

Comment: Gee, thanks for the compliment and response, it really makes my day.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the `Button` click gesture is clashing/overriding the `CollectionView` selection gesture.

The simplest solution is to remove the `Button` to re-obtain the selection gesture. In lieu of the `Button` you can put a `Frame` + `Label`.

Move the event handlers to `SelectedChanged` or `SelectedChangedCommand` and/or read the value in `SelectedItem`.

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<CollectionView x:Name="myCollectionView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Characters}"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                SelectionChanged="myCollectionView_SelectionChanged">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="characters:Character">
            <Frame Margin="10">
                <Label Text="{Binding Value}"/>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                        <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Lime" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>
                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

```cs
// Character.cs
public class Character
{
    public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public List<Character> Characters { get; }
        = "Q,W,E,R,T,Y"
        .Split(',')
        .Select(c => new Character { Value = c })
        .ToList();

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = this;
    }

    private void myCollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine($"Selection changed: {myCollectionView.SelectedItem}");
    }
}
```

A variation is you could create a `TwoWay` binding on `SelectedItem`:

```xml
<CollectionView SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCharacter, Mode=TwoWay}">
</CollectionView>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs

    private Character _selectedCharacter;
    public Character SelectedCharacter
    {
        get => _selectedCharacter;
        set
        {
            _selectedCharacter = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCharacter));
            // can do more stuff here
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had tried this and tried again. The same situation occurs, it works fine on Windows, but the frame is not clickable on Android. However, it works when you click outside the line of the Frame control.

Comment: Okay, even the Frame may be receiving events. To avoid that, you might have to set `IsEnabled="False"`

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried and it didn't work. There is no problem in WinUi.